# Sum of vector of vectors of vectors ... of integers

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I'm trying to sum all the elements of a vector of vectors of vectors ... of integers: something like a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>>` where there's no need to every layer have the same size.

I would like to accomplish it using template, so I did it:

```
namespace nn
{
    template < class T >
    int sumAllElements(std::vector<T> v)
    {
        int size = v.size();
        int output = 0;

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
        {
                                                //should call the function below 
            output += sumAllElements( v[ i ] ); //or this function, depending in 
                                                //which "layer" we are
        }

        return output;
    }

    int sumAllElements(std::vector<int> v)
    {
        int size = v.size();
        int output = 0;

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
        {
            output += v[ i ]; //we've reached the bottomest layer,
                              //so just sum everybory
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

BUT, this is happening:

```
CMakeFiles\test.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
D:/test/main.cpp:49: undefined reference to `int nn::sumAllElements<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >(std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\test\build.make:141: test.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/test.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: test] Error 2
```

I really don't know why...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Name lookup in templates is non-trivial.

Comment: I can't see if the question was downvoted...

Comment: What about writing `int sumAllElements(int x)` instead of a `vector<int>` and just `return x`?

Comment: @zahir, can you explain better?

Comment: Given your last comments, this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Yes! Extremely related! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your error message. It looks like your functions are in a separate compilation unit from main.cpp. If your functions are in a .h file, `#include` the header file in main.cpp.

I would suggest using the template specialization declaration:

```
template<>
int sumAllElements(std::vector<int> v)
{
 ...   
}
```

Another, unrelated suggestion, would be to pass the vectors by const reference. Currently, you are passing them by value which could be costly if the vectors are large.

Comment: As you said, the problem was where I placed the function. I have

a .h with the namespace nn with its functions sumAllElements and the declaration of a class;

a .cpp with the definition of the class's methods and the namespace method (which are both of the sumAllElements forms);

main.cpp, where I included the .h, but seems the sumAllElements can't be found... And I don't understand why... If I put these functions inside main.cpp, it works (just like @Bob__ did).

Comment: @HenriqueGarcia the `template<>` is template specialization. This means you are defining an explicit implementation for the `std::vector<int>` type. I don't know why it is not compiling with the functions defined in a .h file. You would have to show all of your code and state which files they are in.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a function that hasn't been declared yet. Templates can sometimes make that problem go away, but not always. And this is one of the cases where you simple need a declaration of `int sumAllElements(std::vector<int> v)` prior to `template < class T > int sumAllElements(std::vector<T> v)`

Comment: Well, I just tried it, but didn't work: got the same error.

Comment: @HenriqueGarcia Give also the standard library a try, it's full of useful algorithms: https://ideone.com/VU8X8A

Comment: @Bob__, thanks. Indeed you're right. And I also realized that the (worst) problem is about how I organized the project, wich is in a comment of the accepted question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to enable/disable the specialization that is needed:

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, int> = 0>
auto sum_all(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    T sum = 0;

    for (auto& e : v)
    {
        sum += e;
    }

    return sum;
}

template <class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, int> = 0>
auto sum_all(const std::vector<T>& nested_v)
{
    decltype(sum_all(nested_v[0])) sum = 0;

    for (auto& e : nested_v)
    {
        sum += sum_all(e);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

See it [on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9b34fb3e1ecde32)

---

With C++17 you can have just one function (neat!):

```
template <class T>
auto sum_all(const std::vector<T>& nested_v)
{
    innermost_type_t<T> sum = 0;

    for (auto& e : nested_v)
    {
        if constexpr(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value)
            sum += e;
        else
            sum += sum_all(e);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

With `innermost_type_t` defined as:

```
template <class T> struct innermost_type
{
    using type = T;
};

template <class T> struct innermost_type<std::vector<T>>
{
    using type = typename innermost_type<T>::type;
};

template <class T>
using innermost_type_t = typename innermost_type<T>::type;
```

Comment: H%lly sh!t! hahahah Good to know. Thanks :)